# I have some buttons, i need to turn one red on click and old red button grey how do i do this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Html:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <form>
        <button class="all active" type="button">All</button>
        <button class="print-temp" type="button">Print template</button>
        <button class="web-temp" type="button">Web template</button>
        <button class="user-inter" type="button">user interface</button>
        <button class="mock-up" type="button">mock-up</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Js:

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons form button");
for(let button of buttons) {
console.log(button);
button.onclick = function() {
    buttons.classList.remove("active") //making old active button not active
    button.classList.add("active") //making new active button
};
console.log(button);
}
```

Every time i click on any button i get this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
at HTMLButtonElement.button.onclick (main.js:8)
```

What's wrong? Is it ".buttons form button"?

Comment: The reason why there's a `for(let button of buttons)` is the same reason why `buttons.classList` won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if any button has `active` class. If so then use `remove` to remove the class.

Also `buttons` here `buttons.classList.remove("active")` refers to the collection but not individual element

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons form button");
for (let button of buttons) {
  button.onclick = function() {
    const getActiveBtn = document.querySelector('button.active');
    if (getActiveBtn) {
      getActiveBtn.classList.remove("active")
    }
    button.classList.add("active")


  };

}
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <form>
    <button class="all active" type="button">All</button>
    <button class="print-temp" type="button">Print template</button>
    <button class="web-temp" type="button">Web template</button>
    <button class="user-inter" type="button">user interface</button>
    <button class="mock-up" type="button">mock-up</button>
  </form>
</div>
```